# How to schedule the execution of a unix-script without using cron?

Tags: unix

I have a Wrapper-Script running several scripts at once. I would like to schedule the wrapper to be run every friday morning. Cron jobs are disabled for this server, therefore I cannot use cron.

What would be the best way to schedule the execution of a unix-script wihtout using cron?

Cheers

Comment: Well, you obviously can implement your own small deamon waking up every now and then, checking the current date and time and deciding if anything is to be done. So some form of "poor mans cron". But why not enable the tools that is exactly the right one for what you want to do?

Comment: An obvious alternative would be to trigger execution from _outside_, for example by making an ssh login and executing a script or by a http request to a server which triggers the local execution.

Comment: I am not in the position to enable the right tools nor can I change this decision. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: I'd say that the second comment I made suggests alternatives you do not really need special tools or permissions for, assuming that you have access to that system _at all_.

Comment: Triggering the execution from outside seems good. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Options to Schedule a script -

1. Schedule script execution using Task Scheduler of Windows, which
   will login to Server to execute the script. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312999/running-shell-script-with-windows-task-scheduler)
2. Expect command of unix which can allows to login to Another Server
   and execute the script. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147566/expect-script-for-remote-ssh-login-and-executing-commands)